# C++ std::vector remove MyClass object

Tags: c++, vector

If I have a std::vector and at some point through the code I add an instance of a MyClass object, later on how can I remove THAT particular object from the vector?

(I found a question on SO which explained how to remove ints, but they are primitive and I dont know if the same technique would work with user-defined classes)

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
MyClass m;
v.push_back(m);
.
.
.
//Wish to remove m from v??
```

EDIT: You do not know the position of m in the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you know it is still the last element:

```
v.pop_back();
```

Else

```
auto it=std::find(begin(v),end(v),m);
if(it!=end(v)) v.erase(it);
```

Note, that `push_back` duplicates `m` via it's copy ctor, it is not the same `m` as in the code that calls `push_back` it just has the same value (unlike say Java semantics).

EDIT:

`op==` and `op<` can be implemented like so.

```
struct s {
    std::string name;
    int id;
};

bool operator==(const s& l, const s& r) {
    return l.id   == r.id
    &&     l.name == r.name
    ;
}

bool operator<(const s& l, const s& r) {
     return std::make_tuple(l.id, l.name)
     <      std::make_tuple(r.id, r.name)
     ;
}
```

Comment: No- you do not know the position

Comment: Well then follow the second example?

Comment: Do I have to declare an assignment operator (or a copy constructor) for MyClass to use the second approach? I'm getting "error : no operator "==" matches these operands
1>              operand types are: MyClass == const MyClass"

Comment: Yes your class will need an `operator==`.

Comment: I havent done one of these before, would you be able to help me out a little? And can I just do the equation based upon memory address, or would it have to be some sort of ID data member?

Comment: `std::tie` might be cheaper than `std::make_tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be aware that the vector stores its own copy of `m`. So you need to define a criteria for something that is equivalent to `m`. Then you can use `std::find` or `std::find_if` to get an iterator to the first equivalent instance, and call `std::vector::erase` to remove it.

Assuming equivalenve is defined via an `operator==(const MyClass&, const MyClass&)`, then

```
auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), m);
if(it != v.end()) 
  v.erase(it);
```

To use other criteria:

```
bool eq(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) { .... }
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), eq);
if(it != v.end()) 
  v.erase(it);
```

Here, `eq` could be replaced by a functor instance or a lambda expression.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on how far you are going to carry the vector around in your code, you could store a pointer to m instead (`std::vector<MyClass*> v; v.push_back(&m);`). That may actually have some added benefits, but of course you have to be careful that `m` doesn't go out of scope while `v` continues to exist.

Comment: I think I have just stumbled across the reason you mention operator==(). I get this error message: "error : no operator "==" matches these operands
1>              operand types are: MyClass == const MyClass"

Comment: Is that because I need to define the operator==? How would this operator generally be done?

Answer (score 0):

C++11:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
auto end = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 3);
v.resize(end - v.begin());
```